# Place yammer sharebutton in next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, yammer

Placing Yammer share button in next.js sounds like a simple task. Reading the [documentation](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/share-button) from yammer its seems like it was just to add the source in the `Head Component` and call it with the `<span id="yj-share-button"></span>`

```
    export default function YammerButton() {
      return (
          <>
          <Head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s0.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_social_buttons.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">yam.platform.yammerShare();</script>
         </Head>
          <span id="yj-share-button"></span>
          </>   
     )

};
```

It did not work for this solution, how's the proper way to do this in next.js?

Comment: Can you clarify where are you setting the `Head` component? Additional code around that would be helpful.

Comment: Ok, I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert JavaScript code directly like that in the `<script>` tag. You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop for that.

You'll also need to move the scripts to a custom `_document` instead, so it gets rendered on first load.

```js
// pages/_document.js

class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
        </Head>

        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
          <script
            type="text/javascript"
            src="https://s0.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_social_buttons.min.js"
          />
          <script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: "yam.platform.yammerShare();"
            }}
          />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
```

Then to render simply add the `span`.

```js
export default function YammerButton() {
    return (
        <span id="yj-share-button"></span> 
    )
};
```

Comment: I had some trouble with this to work. There was nothing rendering from this.

Comment: I see your setup its working fine, and i have the same setup in my App. I render the <span> in menu.js. Getting error : Please specify an element with id='yj-share-button' or pass options as specified in developer.yammer.com

Comment: Are you certain you are rendering `<span id="yj-share-button"></span>`? That error would indicate otherwise.

Comment: If i would have wrote <span id="yj-share-button">Hello world</span>, the Hello world text would only be rendered, thats confuse me.